# How to force open TCP 443 on my machine?

Tags: network, firewall, tcp

I turned off the firewall. Then, using **nmap** in the **terminal**, I issued the statement

```
nmap 127.0.0.1
```

and got

```
Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-08-15 11:00 PHT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00016s latency).
Not shown: 968 closed ports, 27 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
631/tcp  open  ipp
3306/tcp open  mysql
9000/tcp open  cslistener
```

How can I force open TCP 443 on my machine?

Comment: What process or program do you want to listen on port 443? (or how did you get port 80 open assuming you want a web server to listen on both?)

Answer (score 2):

To force open any port you can use `nc` (netcat).

The command `sudo nc -l 443` will open port 443. Of course this will not serve any web pages. But it will be listed in your namp output as open port.

By specifying an interface with `-b <if>` you can bind it exclusively to it - other interfaces (e.g. en1) shouldn't show an open port 443 then:

```
sudo nc -b en0 -l 443
```

Check for more options by executing `man nc`.