# Can I Open Port 443 on my MacMini without using the Server App?

Tags: network, high-sierra, mac-mini, osx-server, firewall

I'm using an AT&T router where I have port 443 open. I did a port scan and it does not show 443 open. I have the firewall open with all the default options listed that Allow incoming connections.

I'm using Let's Encrypt on my development MacMini server for my SSL certificates. I'm having a problem with accessing my website. I contacted the Let's Encrypt forum and was told that my problem was that port 443 was blocked.

This is the only option that I found so far that claims to force open a port. This solution is three years old. I'm not familiar with netcat so I'm reluctant to use it without more understanding on how this works?

[How to force open TCP 443 on my machine?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249407/how-to-force-open-tcp-443-on-my-machine)

I've also read several solutions that use the Server app. I'm not using the Server app because I had problems with it a while ago. Is there another clean option to turn this port on that does not use it? I'll install it if I need to but I prefer another option if one is available.

UPDATE 03/13/2019: I just installed the latest version of macOS Server to try and open port 443. The vast majority of features that were available in older versions of the Server app have been removed so I need to find another option to get this done.

Comment: The port should already be open unless you have Firewall turned on. You do, however, need something to listen on port 443. This requires having some software running that is listening for it. You shouldn't need to do anything special because it's on macOS

Comment: I thought that was the case but with the Firewall off Network Utility did not show port 443 when I did a port scan. It used to years ago from what I remember. Ports 80 and 88 show up but not 443. This is my output when I execute wget.

[myfolder (master)]$ wget https://mydomain.com/
--2019-03-12 16:32:45--  https://mydomain.com/
Resolving mydomain.com (mydomain.com)... 999.999.999.999
Connecting to mydomain.com (mydomain.com)|999.999.999.999|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.

I may be wrong thinking the port is blocked but it does not show up.

Answer (score 1):

"443... connected. Unable to establish SSL connection" means that the problem isn't related to port 443 being blocked; your version of wget is probably stale (see this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817876/wget-ssl-alert-handshake-failure).)

Try `curl` instead: `curl https://mydomain.com`

(Note: the "https://" part is important!)

Comment: I just tried the curl command; I got the error: curl: (7) Failed to connect to lightbe.lightbe.com port 443: Connection refused. Port 443 does not show up in Network Utility  when I do a Port Scan like it used to. I need to figure out why or come up with a way to open it since the Server App removed that functionality.

Comment: Thanks! That information helps a lot. `nmap` says ports 443 and 80 are closed, about which the nmap manual says "Closed: ports have no application listening on them, though they could open up at any time." In other words, it sounds likely that the web server isn't running, or isn't listening on those ports. Which web server are you using? Apache? (To reproduce my results, use `nmap -v -APn lightbe.lightbe.com` For comparison, also enter `nmap -v -APn 127.0.0.1` in a terminal on the macmini. If the PORT column doesn't include 443, there's your problem.)

Comment: Bill, when I try to execute nmap it says nmap: command not found.

Comment: I use Slack, GitHub for Mac and Grammarly. When I execute lsof -Pn -i4 | grep :443 it says Closed for GitHub and Established for the others. I'm using Apache. I will need to figure out how to get Apache to listen to them. I thought I had all of that set up. I'm updating/private//etc/httpd.conf. I include httpd_ssl.conf. I load the module mod_ssl.so. I know there is another config file that the Server app uses. Do I need to update that one instead? If so, I forget where it is. It's been years since I have done this. I don't use the Server app.

Comment: You can install nmap (https://nmap.org/book/install.html) or use a package manager like Homebrew to get it. As far as Apache configuration goes, it's been a while since I looked at that as well, but there's LOTS of great material available online for that kind of thing. FWIW, I'd recommend getting a second set of eyes on the problem directly. If you happen to be in northwest or central Ohio, I can help you (dm me), but otherwise you might want to look for help at the local Apple, Web, etc. user group meetups. (Try meetup.com; it's a good source.)

Comment: I’m in the Midwest. I found out how to install nmap using homebrew. There is another apache confie file /etc/apache2/extra/http-default.conf I may try and update. If that does not work I may check local groups. This is not a production server. I’m trying to test Ruby on Rails websites before deploying to Heroku. My problem will be finding people hosting websites on Mac computers. Thanks so much! I will post what happens when I update the other config file.